# Proving a graph doesn't have a perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

> Consider the following graph:
>
> [image]
>
> Find a perfect matching or prove one doesn't exist.

I don't think a perfect matching exists here, as the vertices $a_2, a_3$ and $a_4$ are problematic to us, but I'm having some trouble proving this. Using Hall's theorem, we can prove that a matching of a certain cardinality doesn't exist, but how am I supposed to know the cardinality of the perfect matching in order to prove my claim? Can someone give me a hint how to apply the theorem here?

**EDIT**: Can I assume that the cardinality of the perfect matching $|M| = 2$, as the smallest vertex cover is {$a_5, a_4$}, and then find two vertices that break Hall's condition?

Comment: The graph contains two disjoint graphs, each with an odd number of vertices.

Comment: One thing you could do is just [run a max flow algorithm](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/matching.pdf) to find the maximum matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a perfect matching $M$ exists.  Note that $b_2$ has degree $2$, so either $\{b_2,a_2\}\in M$ or $\{b_2,a_5\}\in M$.

**Case I.** $\{b_2,a_2\}\in M$.  Then, $\{b_3,a_5\}\in M$.  Hence, $\{b_5,a_6\}\in M$.  Now, $b_6$ cannot be paired.

**Case II.** $\{b_2,a_5\}\in M$.  Hence, $\{b_5,a_6\}\in M$.  Now, $b_6$ cannot be paired.

Comment: We could've used a similar argument for $b_3$ instead of $b_2$, correct?

Comment: @Katja  Yes, there are other choices as well.  For example, you can show that $\{a_1,b_1\}$ and $\{a_4,b_4\}$ are both in $M$, or $\{a_1,b_4\}$ and $\{a_4,b_1\}$ are both in $M$.  Therefore, $a_3$ cannot be paired.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel Mathias gave the hint;

The graph $G$ is disconnected. Subgraph generated by $\{a_2,b_2,b_3,a_5,a_6,b_5,b_6\}$ is one component and subgraph generated by $\{a_1,a_3,a_4,b_1,b_4\}$ is another component.

Now if $G$ has a perfect matching then both components also have perfect matching. But none of the components have perfect matching because each has odd number of vertices (Reason: A graph has perfect matching with $M$ edges then it necessarily has $2M$ vertices).

Comment: I think you men $2M$ vertices, not $2M$ edges.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Hall's Marriage Theorem can be used to prove that the above bipartite graph does not admit a perfect matching.

**Hall's Marriage Theorem:** Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with $A$ and $B$ as partite sets. Then $G$ contains a perfect matching if and only if:

$1 . |A| = |B|$

$2 . |S| \leq |N(S)|,$  $\forall$ $S$ $\subseteq$ $A$

where $S$ is any subset of $A$ consisting of vertices of $A$, and $N(S)$ (read: neighbors of $S$) is the set of vertices in $B$ that are adjacent to the vertices of $S$. Formally,
$N(S) = $ {$b_{i}$ $\in$ $B:$ $a_{i}$ ~ $b_{i}$ for all $a_{i}$ $\in$ $S$}

In the given graph, the first condition is clearly satisfied, as the cardinality of both the partite sets is the same (which is 6).

However, the second condition is violated. Choose $S$ $=$ {$a_{1}$, $a_{3}$, $a_{4}$}. Then $N(S)$ = {$b_{1}$, $b_{4}$}. Clearly in this case, $|S| > |N(S)|$, thus violating the second condition of Hall's Marriage Theorem.

As it is a necessary condition for a bipartite graph to admit a perfect matching, it follows that the given bipartite graph has no perfect matching.